# What is the address_formats.xml file?

Tags: magento2

I noticed that Magento 2 has `address_formats.xml`. What is this file used for?

Answer (score 0):

`address_formats.xml` is Address Format Declaration config file. It declares all available formats for **Address Templates** in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

See this Overview of module configuration files for reference https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/files/module-files.html